# how to catch exception for call?

Tags: android, android-intent, call

on my app i'have to make a call to a number.
Code work's fine on mobile phone, but on tablet (that can't make call) app crashed.
I want to catch this exception.

```
 try{
          String toDial = "tel:092168*****";
          startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(toDial)));}
  catch(Exception e){
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Chiamata non supportata", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                      }
```

but don't work.
idea?
sorry for my bad english

Comment: If you paste the `LogCat` output, we can see the problem (it is probably the `Intent.ACTION_CALL`). You can also print the actual exception if you manage to catch it with your block there and see what it is.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first check that whether the `Intent` is available or not with the code below

```
public static boolean isAvailable(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
           final PackageManager mgr = ctx.getPackageManager();
           List<ResolveInfo> list =
              mgr.queryIntentActivities(intent, 
                 PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
           return list.size() > 0;
 }
```